# Rounded rectangle user control, non consistent arcs

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

im trying to create a rounded rectangle for a usercontrol but the addarc() is not consistent. I found the following link and have been trying to recreate what LarsTech mentions in c#, thus far unsuccessfully. I would appreciate it if someone could give me some pointers on how this could be implemented in c#. Thanks.

[LarsTech's Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060525/rounded-rectangle-not-accurate)

Comment: @Silvermind: thats odd when i click on it it works. Here is the link i mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060525/rounded-rectangle-not-accurate

Comment: Let me know if it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reproduce this:

```
Private Sub DrawRoundRect(ByVal g As Graphics, ByVal r As Rectangle)
  Dim hDC As IntPtr = g.GetHdc
  Dim hPen As IntPtr = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 0, ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Red))
  ...
End Sub
```

you need to use unsafe code in C#. Not the easy way if you didn't do this before, but maybe great to learn (you need it sooner or later). Start with documentation about `Platform Invoke` (MSDN). The you can do coding. You can probably find all functions as `P/Invoke` here: http://www.pinvoke.net/ to save you some typing.

`P/Invoke` tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Your right, i have not covered unsafe code yet. I will have a look into the links you have provided. Thanks very much.

Comment: Have book marked your links and will come back to this at a later date but atm its a little over my head. Thanks for your help though, im sure i will find them useful once i have a better understanding of this.